# Tried to implement selection sort in java but result comes out wrong

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have written this code to implement selection sort, but for some reason it does not work as intended.

To be exact, my only problem is that after I find the first min, the program repeats that min all the way through. So if the min were to be 15, I would get 15 in every element.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
for(count=0;count<sort.length;count++){          
        min = 100;
        for (counter=0;counter<sort.length;counter++){
            if(sort[counter]<min ){
                //&& sort[counter]>lastMin;
                min = sort[counter];
                elementNumber = counter;
            }
        }
        temp = sort[count];
        sort[count] = min;
        sort[elementNumber] = temp;
    }
```

After making some alterations the code now looks like this:

```
for(count=0;count<sort.length;count++){          
        min = sort[count];         
        for (counter=(count + 1);counter<sort.length;counter++){
            if(sort[counter]<min ){
                min = sort[counter];
                elementNumber = counter;
            }
        }
        temp = sort[count];
        sort[count] = min;
        sort[elementNumber] = temp;
    }
```

Now what is happening is that i sometimes get duplicates in the sorted list

Comment: Home work assignment? Check out the selection sort algorithm, and you probably spot your error quickly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: To be exact my only problem is that after i find the first min, the program repeats that min all the way through
so if the min were to be 15, I would get 15 in every element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several big problems.

1. Don't initialize min to 100, initialize it to the first value of the
   remaining data: `sort[count]`.
2. For each iteration of the outer loop, start the inner loop from
   `count + 1` and proceed from there to see if you can find something
   smaller than the current min. By starting at 0 you keep finding the
   smallest value in the array as a whole rather than the smallest value in the
   remainder of the array.
3. Once you find the min of the remaining data, you should **swap** it
   with `sort[count]`.  Assignment blows away the value that used to be
   in  `sort[count]`.  This, combined with point 2, is why you keep getting the same value
   repeated in your output.

Comment: Thanks for your help
I did all of the above, and the result comes out 'correct, with the exception of a few duplicates or an occasional flip between two
3
5
20
36
85
63
74
70
77
23
this is the end of the unsorted list
20
5
20
23
36
63
63
70
70
77

Answer (score 0):

When you overwrite the entry at location **count** with the line:

```
sort[count] = min;
```

you will lose the previous contents of the array at that index.

You need to keep track of the location of the minimum and perform a swap instead.

Comment: for(count=0;count<sort.length;count++){          
            min = 100;
               
            for (counter=0;counter<sort.length;counter++){
                if(sort[counter]<min ){
                    //&& sort[counter]>lastMin;
                    min = sort[counter];
                    elementNumber = counter;
                }
            }
            temp = sort[count];
            sort[count] = min;
            sort[elementNumber] = temp;
        }

I changed it to this now, still doesnt work yet but i think i'm a step closer, i'll continue to play around it a little bit

Comment: @user3298275 Try starting your second loop at count instead of at 0 in order to skip over the sorted elements.  Good luck!